# SQL - Create a join / query based on the results of another query. The Join table would be from the results of another query

Tags: sql, join, dynamic

I hope you can help me.

I need to create a query which will use the values from a dynamic result to use as the left join table.

For example:

This query will return different values all the time. Based on the each @itemid.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Reference]
FROM TABLE_ABC
WHERE ID = @ItemId
```

Then using this 'Reference' values, I need to left join on that values and also return the sum for that as for the query below. 
The query below works perfect, if I hard coded the Reference in each left join. 
But I need to make this all dynamic that it will create the query depending on the number of Reference items it returns.

```
SELECT 
SUM(x.Value)  [Ref A],
SUM(x1.Value) [Ref B],
SUM(x2.Value) [Ref C]
FROM TABLE_YZ yz
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ABC x   ON yz.id = x.id AND x.Reference = 'Ref A'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ABC x1  ON yz.id = x.id AND x1.Reference = 'Ref B'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ABC x2  ON yz.id = x.id AND x2.Reference = 'Ref C'
```

Could anybody give me some advice on how to create this script? 
Or what shall I search for?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Anderson

** Sample Results:

Total ----     Ref A    ----    Ref B   ----    Ref C   ----    Ref D    ----   Ref E   ----   and so on…..

1,000.00   ----     100.00  ----    200.00  ----    300.00   ----   250.00  ----    250.00

Comment: Just change the joined table to a sub query with brackets () and give it an alias

Comment: what RDBMS? mySQL, SQL server?  guessing SQL server since [] are used.  AND.... it table_yz your distinct list from the 1st query? and lastly do they need to be columns?  this seems like it would be easier as a group by or using analytic.

Comment: SQL Server - Thank you

Comment: budirec - thanks for that. unfortunately I cannot see what you mean. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: I for one would need to see some sample data with expected results I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: xQbert - Thanks. Yes, needs to be columns. Adding a sample in the original post.

Comment: Will you always have the same number of references and consistent datatypes? If so you can hardcode your query to a temp table and then dynamically insert your changing references into that table when needed. Alternatively if the number of references is subject to change you can dynamically write your SQL script (using whatever language is available to you) and then perform a CALL or EXECUTE *Script*; (depending on your RDBMS) at the end of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why something like this wouldn't work.  It gives you rows instead of columns...

```
Select Sum(x.value), reference
from table_abc
where ID = @itemID
group by reference
```

If you need columns, you could use dynamic SQL and pivot the columns. or if you always know there will be 3 references, we can do something different with case statements and a row number.

Comment: xQbert - Thanks- It needs to be in columns for displaying purpose. The pivot columns might work. The number of columns is unknown

Comment: xQbert - if I use the exaple you provided, it will sum all the values to be the same, and it will not sum the values based on each individual Reference.

Comment: @user2216540  I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work after the 2nd comment.    It seemed like it should be a simple group by aside from pivoting rows to columns.  Normally this can be done in the reporting tool or PHP or.net or whatever app is rending the results from the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Is this kinda of what you need?

```
SELECT 
SUM(x.Value)  [Ref A],
SUM(x1.Value) [Ref B],
SUM(x2.Value) [Ref C],
SUM(x3.Value) [Ref D]
FROM TABLE_YZ yz
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ABC x   ON yz.id = x.id AND x.Reference = 'Ref A'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ABC x1  ON yz.id = x.id AND x1.Reference = 'Ref B'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ABC x2  ON yz.id = x.id AND x2.Reference = 'Ref C'
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Reference]
           FROM TABLE_ABC
           WHERE ID = @ItemId) x3 ON yz.id = x.id AND x3.Reference = 'Ref D'
```